# How to add style (font-size) to certain tags in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So Im making bootstrap cards (with an image, title, description, links etc). The descriptions vary in length, from 50-250 chars and I want it to fit a fixed width and height. So I was thinking getting the length of the description and popping it into an if statement to change the font-size.

But applying the font-size **just** to the descriptions that are over a certain length, is where I'm running into trouble.

Here is where the HTML is formed in the function:

`card.innerHTML = "<div class='card'><img class='card-img-top' src='" + imgAddress + "' alt='Image'><div class='card-block'><h4 class='card-title'>" + title + "</h4><span class='desc'>" + desc + "</span><a href='" + linkAddress + "' download><button class='btn btn-primary'>View on our website</button></a>"+ addSpreadsheet + "</div><div class='card-footer'>Expires: "+ endDate + "</div></div>";`

A bit messy, so essentially we just need this line

`<span class='desc'>" + desc + "</span>`

Is there any way I could add an ID, or class to particular spans? I could get it working if I changed the font size of the entire card, but thats obviously not gonna work.

Let me know if you'd require more info or code. But I think that looks to be enough.

Comment: I used fixed length of strings in this kind of situations. you can do it with PHP or as well as JavaScript. use substr() in PHP to short the description text.

Comment: I need to be able to accommodate longer strings. Its a situation where I cant compromise for the sake of better code.

Comment: Then can't you hide the text without limiting? and add 'view more desc' button to your cards?

Answer (score 1):

I write an example for you

HTML :

```
<!--This p Tag contain 245 chars , We are going to limit it using javascript-->
<p id="desc">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui consequatur magnam facilis quas dignissimos voluptate tempore, reiciendis quidem quam fuga asperiores, blanditiis inventore modi assumenda maiores mollitia alias perferendis fugiat.
</p>
```

java script :

```
 var e = document.getElementById('desc').innerHTML;
 console.log(e.length); //245
 var newDesc ="";
 for(var i=0; i<=e.length-1; i++){
    if(i<100) //Limit it to what ever you want, I limit it to 100
        newDesc += e[i];
    else
        break;
 }
  console.log(newDesc.length);// 100
  document.getElementById('desc').innerHTML= newDesc;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/t2ekv8w7/